# Scraping Snapdeal to extract the Mobile phone features

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to scrape  the mobile product features from snapdeal.

```
//*[@id="productSpecs"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]
//*[@id="productSpecs"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]
```

these are the xpaths. I can see the results via scraper extention in google chrome.But cant fetch the results through scrapy.

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
# from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from demo.items import CraigslistSampleItem


class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "craigs"
    allowed_domains = ["www.snapdeal.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.snapdeal.com/product/samsung-galaxy-j2-8gb/655619199985"]

    def parse(self, response):
        # hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sel = Selector(response)
        titles = sel.xpath("//*[@id='productSpecs']/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]")
        print titles
        items = []
        for titles in titles:
            item = CraigslistSampleItem()
            # item["Brand"] = titles.extract()
            items.append(item)
        print items
```

`titles` is prints empty, this is the sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your xpath as:

```
titles = sel.xpath("//*[@id='productSpecs']/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/table[1]/tr/td/table/tr/td[2]")
```

This happens because chrome adds extra `tbody` tag in the source code.